Given two sets $A$ and $B$, describe sets $A^C \cup B^C$ and $A^C \cap B^C$
Given $\mathbb{R}$ as a universal set,
and sets $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: 0 \lt x \le 2\}$, $ B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: 1 \le x \lt 4\}$, we need to describe sets $A^C \cup B^C$ and $A^C \cap B^C$. We proceed as follows:
$
A^C \cup B^C 
\iff
(x \notin A) \lor (x \notin B) 
\iff 
(\text{it is not the case that} \, (0 \lt x \le 2) \lor (\text{it is not the case that} \, (1 \le x \lt 4)
\iff
((x \le 0) \lor (x \gt 2)) \lor ((x \lt 1) \lor (x \ge 4))
.
$
When we arrive at the last expression, how can it be simplified even further? What question should we ask at this moment?
I also have an almost exactly the same question about $A^C \cap B^C$. Given $((x \le 0) \lor (x \gt 2)) \land ((x \lt 1) \lor (x \ge 4))$, how can this expression be simplified? What question should I ask at this point?

I assume they want something like $A^c\cup B^c=(A\cap B)^c$.

Try looking up De Morgan's Laws, I think that would answer your question.

I believe it should be $((x\leq 0)\vee (x>2))$

Also, to simplify, note that everything is union in the first case; so its simplifies quite straightforwardly. Try it! Then try to rewrite what you get in simpler terms.

I corrected the mistake in the problem description that @PCeltide pointed out.

For the first one, you can remove the brackets:
$$(x\le0)\vee (x>2)\vee (x<1)\vee (x\ge4)$$
Then, note that
$$\begin{align}
(x\le0)\vee(x<1)=(x<1)\\
(x>2)\vee(x\geq4)=(x\geq4)\end{align}$$
So, the statement simplifies to $(x<1)\vee(x\geq4)$.
For the second statement, you can perhaps use these
$$\begin{align}
A\vee(B\wedge C)=(A\vee B)\wedge(A\vee C)\\
A\wedge(B\vee C)=(A\wedge B)\vee(A\wedge C)\end{align}$$
if you really want an argument by pure manipulation of $\vee$s and $\wedge$s.
But otherwise, you can simply argue like this:

$x\leq0$ and $x<1$ implies $x\leq0$.
$x\leq0$ and $x\ge4$ are not possible together.

The other two are similar and you should be able to write down the final answer.

I will elaborate on why
$$(x\le0)\vee(x<1)\iff(x<1)$$
Call the first statement $P(x)$ and the second one $Q(x)$. Then, if for some $x$, the statement $P(x)$ is true then $x\le0$ or $x<1$. If $x\le0$, then $x<1$ since $0<1$. If $x<1$, then $x<1$ anyway. So, $P(x)\implies Q(x)$.
Also, if $Q(x)$ is true for some $x$, then $x<1$ is true so $P(x)$ is true as well.
Hope this helps. :)

Can you please elaborate on how me achieve elimination? That is, given the following statements: \begin{align}
(x\le0)\vee(x<1)=(x<1)\
(x>2)\vee(x\geq4)=(x\geq4)\end{align} Why are we allowed to use an equal sign here?

@VladMikheenko replace the equals signs with biconditionals. Is it clear now?

@Malady, I am afraid I cannot use biconditionals here because the LHS and the RHS are not logically equivalent.

@VladMikheenko: They are? What's the problem with writing $$(x\leq0)\vee(x<1)\iff(x<1)$$(the implicit assumption being $x\in\Bbb R$)?

Can you please explain why this is allowed? This is exactly the point where I struggle.

@VladMikheenko if $x\leq 0$ then $x<1$. Like just think about it.

@VladMikheenko: I have edited my answer.
